# Малообеспеченный ребенок

Tags: лексика

Уважаемые коллеги, пожалуйста, ответьте на вопрос: правомочно ли употребление словосочетания "малообеспеченные дети и молодежь" или отдельно "малообеспеченный ребенок"?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что вполне правомочно. А почему нет? Собственно, и первый, и второй вариант вполне возможны.